# Issues in running DFS in a graph

Tags: java, string, depth-first-search

Node contains (String from, String to, int time ).
Given a HashMap, key is a String and value is a list of Node with same from.

I want to write a function to find all possible path from a given start point(String start) to end point(String end). I tried to write a dfs function, but it looks it only return one set of result. Anyone can help?

- Node: String from, String to, int time
- List> res: result list of list of node
- List list: temporary list to record current node
- HashMap> graph: key is all from value, value is list of node with the same from
- cur: start with a start value and change each dfs
- end: destination
- visited: a set to record visited to/from

  ```
  private static void dfs(res, list,HashMap<String, List<Node>> graph,String cur, String end, visited){
      if(cur.equals(end)) {
          res.add(new ArrayList<Node>(list));
          return;
      }
      for(Node n : graph.get(cur)) {
          if (visited.contains(n.to)) continue;
          list.add(n);
          visited.add(n.to);
          dfs(res, list, graph, n.to, end, visited);
          list.remove(list.size()-1);
          visited.remove(visited.size()-1);
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the bug is at line

```java
    visited.remove(visited.size()-1);
```

If you look at the [`Set` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove(java.lang.Object)), you'll notice that the only `remove` method is `boolean remove(Object o)` and there is no remove by index as in `List`. So that line is effectively (thanks to auto-boxing):

```java
    visited.remove(Integer.valueOf(visited.size()-1));
```

which is obviously not what you want as it removes nothing. Try to remove last visited node by value instead:

```java
    visited.remove(n.to);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is what I am looking for!